# Perl Inline::C default flags

Tags: perl, inline-c

I made a module using Inline::C and I noticed some unexpected performance discrepancies between running it on the host MacOS vs a guest Linux VM. Looking into it, it was due to the default C compiler flags being different.
On MacOS they appear to be:

```
-fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -O3   -DVERSION=\"0.00\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.00\"
```

Vs on Centos 7:

```
 -fPIC -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2   -DVERSION=\"0.00\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.00\"
```

The main difference for my code is O3 vs O2, so I looked into the Inline docs and used:

```
use Inline (C => Config => ccflags => '-O3');
```

To explicitly specify `-O3`. Well, the result is that `-O3 -O2` is applied that way, so specifying ccflags does not overwrite the default, it just adds *before* them, which in the end does not have any effect.
Any idea where the default comes from and/or how to overwrite it to specify the optimization level that I want.

Comment: Re "*Any idea where the default comes from*", It uses what was used to build the `perl` being used, as returned by `perl -V:ccflags` and `use Config qw( %Config ); $Config{ccflags}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears as though adding the `optimize` configuration option may do what you want. Here's a very short example with the output before adding `optimize => '-O3'` and after:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Inline 'C';

use Inline C => 'Config',
    build_noisy => 1,
    force_build => 1,
    optimize => '-O3',
;

print add(5, 6);

__END__
__C__

int add (int x, int y){
    return(x + y);
}
```

Here's the output (snipped for brevity):

Before:

`cc -c  -I"/home/steve/scratch/inline" -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2`

After:

`cc -c  -I"/home/steve/scratch/inline" -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3`

...on Linux Mint 18.3.

**The default** comes from `$Config{optimize}`, which is stored as a read-only default at the time `perl` was compiled/built on the system.

Comment: You are correct, thanks! Any idea where the default is pulled from and is different on each machine?

Comment: The Inline::C docs refer to the MakeMaker [ccflags](https://perldoc.pl/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#CCFLAGS) and [optimize](https://perldoc.pl/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#OPTIMIZE) settings. These are the same except they have different defaults and are positioned differently in the resulting argument list.

Comment: On my system, it appears this default comes from `$Config{optimize}`, which is stored as a read-only default at the time perl was compiled/built on the system.